# Laravel and Vue-Router : How to add slash at the end of the URL

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue-Router, in a Laravel/VueJs application. Vue Router is used in hash mode, so I expect this kind of URL:

http://base/#/action

http://base/asset/#/action

It currently works if I reach the base url. But as soon as I use another URL, the slash before the hash is removed and the url looks like that : http://base/asset#/action

Here are my routes in laravel:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/asset', 'AssetController@index');
```

I already try to change my route to /asset/ but it didn't fix.
I also try to change this part of the .htaccess but no luck

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So my question is: Why is this working with the base URL, and not with others ? Is this some sort of URL rewriting rules in Laravel ? or in Vue-Router ?

Romain.

Comment: Is your Vue application running on the page at the `/asset` route? If so, try setting the [`base`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) property to `/asset/` when you create your VueRouter instance. For example, `const router = new VueRouter({ routes: routes, base: '/asset/'});`

Comment: Yes the Vue App is running at the /asset route. I tried your solution, but it doesn't fix the issue. My router looks like that : `const router = new VueRouter({
    base: '/asset/',
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: testComp},
        { path: '/search', component: searchTable}
    ]
});`

Comment: The trailing slash is removed from the route because it's not a real directory, so the htaccess rule removes it and and changes `/asset/` to `/asset`, and this happens *before* vue is delivered and loaded in your browser. If you _really_ need that slash (not sure why), you will have to adjust your route _and_ your htaccess rules, which may have a negative impact on the rest of your app depending on other routes.

Comment: Thanks @DarrylE.Clarke for your answer. I was just wondering if this was not gonna bring some problems to manipulate the history, or the url itself. Also, and this is a minor issue, it does not looks good. This is my current URL: 'http://itsm/asset#/search'. I'm new in front end development, but I don't remember seeing this kind of URL. But if you telling me it is normal, then it is fine for me :)

Comment: It shouldn't have any issues with history writing. However, if you want, you can remove the # hash altogether using the vue HTML5 history mode. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations - and - https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel  for references.